# Deleted ng-show leaking $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a situation where I'm receiving json data from a backend and then rendering it using a template which has a few `ng-show` directives.

```
<div>
    <span ng-show="config.displayMode == 'A'" class="ng-binding">${A}</span>
    <span ng-show="config.displayMode == 'B'" class="ng-binding">${B}</span>
    <span ng-show="config.displayMode == 'C'" class="ng-binding">${C}</span>
</div>
```

When I receive the next set of data, because of the way the template works, it simply removes the current elements and renders new elements.

This all works correctly and seems to perform well, but when I look at the Batarang performance tool, I see that I am leaking watches every time the elements are removed. This page tends to stay open for long periods of time and over time the memory footprint and digest time is growing linearly which I'd like to avoid.

**EDIT** The elements are being removed using jQuery's `.empty()` function

Per request I have created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/Noz0bu).  The example is super contrived but basically it apps an element with an `ng-show` each time something is typed in the box.  If the box is emptied than the `ng-show` elements are deleted.  Using batarang you can see that the watches are still present on the performance tab.

**MY Question** Is there a way to clear the watches that are instantiated by an `ng-show` directive?

Comment: How are you removing the elements?

Comment: I'm actually using the [Ignite Grid from Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/grid/) to display the data, so I don't know how it's removing them. I know they are not in the DOM, but I'll crack open the source to figure out how they're being removed

Comment: I looked through the source and it appears to be using jQuery's `.empty()` function to remove all the child nodes

Comment: Can you post a Plunkr with a broader context of what you are trying to achieve? It seems to me that we are dealing with an architectural problem here. 

In angular.js, especially in this case DOM elements should not be removed manually. The only place you could do that is a directive, when you deal with DOM manually. There's couple things I could say, but I need to know more about the code first.

Comment: @RafalPastuszak I have added a plunkr as requested

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, that may solve your problem:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myDirective: '='  
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      $scope.$watch('myDirective', function(){
        if($scope.myDirective.length > 5){
          elem.append("<div class='second'>Length is greater than 5</div>")
        } else {
          elem.empty();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The problem in you code is, that you not really delete the elements from the dom. You simply hide them. So the watchers stay. [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWI2tP)

---

Screenshot of the remaining elements, which will not be removed correctly with your code:
[image]

Comment: Sorry but this does not solve my issue because you aren't using `ng-show` to hide or show anything.  That is the root of the is that when the elements are removed the `$watch` from `ng-show` is staying in scope

Comment: You only hide the elements or empty the them, so for me its no surprise that the $watch stay. The elements still there, but only hidden with the help of CSS. If you want to get rid of the 'old' watcher you must remove the whole elemenent from the DOM.

Comment: The jQuery documentation says this `.empty()` Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM. When I look at the element map in chrome I don't see the elements remaining

Comment: You just empty all elements with the class second. You dont remove the whole element (including the ng-show attribute), only the content. So the watcher still there. See picture in my answer ...

Comment: Oh yes I know that length less than 5 just hides it. Delete all input and the elements will be deleted from the DOM but the watchers will remain.  Like I said, it's a very contrived example

Comment: The elements will not be deleted! Where in your code you delete an element? You just empty the elements with the class second ... in other words you delete the String 'Length is greater than 5', but not the element. Check with browser developer console.

Comment: Oh you are totally correct. I changed the example to be `elem.empty()` now it will remove all the `ng-show` elements.  I still see the `$watches` in the performance tab of batarang